# Lexical environment vs Scope vs Execution context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, executioncontext

What the difference between all of these concepts?
As I understood and become confused:
Scope — This is where our variables, functions, and expressions are created and available.
Lexical environment — it is an object with all of the variables, functions, and expressions.
Execution context – information about all of the variables, functions, and expressions during functions execution.
But then I read some concepts from MDN and now I'm totally confused

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's not what I'm trying to understand. Actually it explains some concepts of scope in JavaScript but, not the difference between lexical environment, scope, and execution context.